# Remove XML element with empty child in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a pass-through proxy web service set up in ESB that grabs data from a DSS endpoint, resembling the following:

```
<Products xmlns="http://wso2.host.com/Products">
    <Product>
        <SKU>12345678</SKU>
        <ItemName xmlns="null">T Shirt</ItemName>
        <Restrictions>
            <Restriction>
                <Reason>Reason A</Reason>
                <Code>12</Code>
            </Restriction>
        </Restrictions>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

There is the possibility that a product may not have a restriction, and will come through as such:

```
<Products xmlns="http://wso2.host.com/Products">
    <Product>
        <SKU>12345678</SKU>
        <ItemName xmlns="null">T Shirt</ItemName>
        <Restrictions>
            <Restriction>
                <Reason/>
                <Code/>
            </Restriction>
        </Restrictions>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I'd like to remove the whole `<Restrictions>` element so the response shows as such:

```
<Products xmlns="http://wso2.host.com/Products">
    <Product>
        <SKU>12345678</SKU>
        <ItemName xmlns="null">T Shirt</ItemName>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I'm trying to use an Enrich mediator in the out sequence to replace it with nothing, but I'm not sure what to use to replace it with, or if that's really the best way to do it. The Xpath expression I have is as follows:

```
/Products/Product/Restrictions[string-length(Restriction/Reason[text()])=0]
```

Any help is super appreciated, I'm not super familiar with WSO2 and might be completely missing the right answer. Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE: I've followed recommendations by @Jorge Infante Osorio and added an XSLT mediator, which references a Local Entry defined as the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restrictions"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This still isn;t working. However, I am able to get them removed by adding 3 XSLT mediators and pointing them at this local entry:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]   |    *[not(node()[2])    and      node()/self::text()    and      not(normalize-space())      ]   " />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried modifying this to match the Restrictions template like @Jorge Infante Osorio had in his example, but I can't seem to get it correct.

Comment: Try changing the match in your last template to `match="Restrictions[not(normalize-space())]"`. If that doesn't work, make sure `Restrictions` is not in a default namespace.

Comment: @DanielHaley your first suggestion didn't work - but I noticed I do have a namespace on the root element that I didn't include. Edited my answer to include this - is that what's affecting the template?

Comment: Yep that's what's doing it. See my answer below. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:p="http://wso2.host.com/Products">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p:Restrictions[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I've accounted for the default namespace `http://wso2.host.com/Products`.

Comment: This did it! Thank you! I also had an Enrich mediator before the XSLT one, had to move it to after the XSLT one for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

As your payload keeps changing based on the output hence it is recommended that you use XSLT mediator, the reason being that your sequence will small in size and readability will increase.

Answer (score 1):

My test proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testReplacement"
       transports="http https"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ACCESO A: "
                      value="Accediendo replacement TEST"/>
         </log>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <Products xmlns="">
                    <Product>
                        <SKU>12345678</SKU>
                        <ItemName>T Shirt</ItemName>
                        <Restrictions>
                            <Restriction>
                                <Reason></Reason>
                                <Code></Code>
                            </Restriction>
                        </Restrictions>
                    </Product>
                  </Products>               
              </format>
              <args>
              </args>
            </payloadFactory>   
            <property name="razon" expression="//Products/Product/Restrictions/Restriction/Reason/text()"/>
            <property name="longitudValue" expression="fn:string-length(get-property('razon'))"/>
            <log level="custom">
              <property name="BODY = " expression="$ctx:body"/>
              <property name="razon" expression="$ctx:razon"/>
              <property name="longitudValue" expression="$ctx:longitudValue"/>
            </log>
            <filter source="$ctx:longitudValue" regex="0.0"> 
               <then> 
                  <log level="custom"> 
                     <property name="RESULTADO" value="Esta vacio"/> 
                  </log> 
                <xslt key="transformacionDeleteEmpty"/>         
                <log level="custom">
                  <property name="BODY = " expression="$ctx:body"/>
                </log>              
               </then> 
               <else> 
                  <log level="custom"> 
                     <property name="RESULTADO" value="No esta vacio"/> 
                  </log> 
               </else> 
            </filter>
            <respond/>          
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <drop/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

And the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="transformacionDeleteEmpty" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restrictions"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

The output in console:

```
[2018-04-06 11:21:53,210]  INFO - LogMediator ACCESO A:  = Accediendo replacement TEST
[2018-04-06 11:21:53,214]  INFO - LogMediator BODY =  = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Products><Product><SKU>12345678</SKU><ItemName>T Shirt</I
temName><Restrictions><Restriction><Reason/><Code/></Restriction></Restrictions></Product></Products></soapenv:Body>, razon = , longitudValue = 0.0
[2018-04-06 11:21:53,215]  INFO - LogMediator RESULTADO = Esta vacio
[2018-04-06 11:21:53,249]  INFO - LogMediator BODY =  = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Products>
  <Product>
    <SKU>12345678</SKU>
    <ItemName>T Shirt</ItemName>
    <Restrictions>
      <Restriction>
        <Reason/>
        <Code/>
      </Restriction>
    </Restrictions>
  </Product>
</Products></soapenv:Body>
[2018-04-06 11:21:53,307]  INFO - LogMediator BODY =  = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Products>
  <Product>
    <SKU>12345678</SKU>
    <ItemName>T Shirt</ItemName>

  </Product>
</Products></soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: I tried this but the end result didn't have the elements removed. Please see my updated question description.

Comment: are you sure?, check in my proxy I use the same XML you had and the output it´s taken from the EI console!!! Maybe it´s because you use ESB 4.0.3 a really old version.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Script-Mediator. For example, below, the username field has been deleted because it is empty:

```
<filter source="json-eval($.loginStatic.request.username)" regex="^null|$">
  <then>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="username==============>" value="****************is empty"/>
    </log>
    <script language="js">
        <![CDATA[                       
                    var message = mc.getPayloadXML();                                               
                    delete message.request.username;
                    mc.setPayloadXML(message);
                ]]>
    </script>
   </then>
   <else>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="username=========>" value="*********************has value"/>
     </log>
   </else>
</filter>
```