# Optional print tag xml and optional tag without value

Tags: wso2

i need little help about how the request field when no value or optional with condition can print at response. i have request json message and want convert to xml with wso2.

sample request

```
"AppHdr" : {
            "Fr" : {
                "FIId" : {
                    "FinInstnId" : {
                        "Othr" : {
                            "Id" : "FASTIDJA"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "To" : {
                "FIId" : {
                    "FinInstnId" : {
                        "Othr" : {
                            "Id" : "INDOIDJA"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "BizMsgIdr" : "20210301FASTIDJA010HRB12345678",
            "MsgDefIdr" : "pacs.002.001.10",
            "BizSvc" : "",
            "CreDt" : "2021-03-01T12:00:00",
            "CpyDplct" : "",
            "PssblDplct" : "",
            "Sgntr" : ""
        },
```

the result response need to fix was like this

```
<ns:AppHdr>
        <ns1:Fr>
            <ns1:FIId>
                <ns1:FinInstnId>
                    <ns1:Othr>
                        <ns1:Id>FASTIDJA</ns1:Id>
                </ns1:Othr>
                </ns1:FinInstnId>
            </ns1:FIId>
        </ns1:Fr>
        <ns1:To>
            <ns1:FIId>
                <ns1:FinInstnId>
                    <ns1:Othr>
                        <ns1:Id>INDOIDJA</ns1:Id>
                    </ns1:Othr>
                </ns1:FinInstnId>
            </ns1:FIId>
        </ns1:To>
        <ns1:BizMsgIdr>20210301FASTIDJA010HRB12345678</ns1:BizMsgIdr>
        <ns1:MsgDefIdr>pacs.002.001.10</ns1:MsgDefIdr>
        <ns1:CreDt>2021-03-01T12:00:00Z</ns1:CreDt>
    </ns:AppHdr>
```

need hint for my case like this. thanks

Comment: Do you want to ignore these fields (CpyDplct, PssblDplct etc.) always? Or ignore only if there are no values assigned to them?

Comment: like optional field. when have value. that value will print. but when the request didnt have any value. xml just keep print. but just tag like <sample></sample> without value at response

Comment: But in your example "CpyDplct" : "" doesn't have a value and <CpyDplct></CpyDplct> is not present.

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue. Check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620455/remove-xml-element-with-empty-child-in-wso2-esb-4-0-3

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT to convert from JSON to XML. [1][2]

Normally people want to eliminate empty tags and you know they are possible from the Schema. But in instances where you want an empty tag you can use the attribute xls:nil=true feature. [3]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/XSLT+Mediator+

[3] https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-set-empty-element-attribute-xslniltrue-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a JSON to XML is by setting the `messageType` property. For example, check the below.

```xml
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
```

Setting the above property alone will Convert your Json to the following XML.

```xml
<AppHdr>
    <Fr>
        <FIId>
            <FinInstnId>
                <Othr>
                    <Id>FASTIDJA</Id>
                </Othr>
            </FinInstnId>
        </FIId>
    </Fr>
    <To>
        <FIId>
            <FinInstnId>
                <Othr>
                    <Id>INDOIDJA</Id>
                </Othr>
            </FinInstnId>
        </FIId>
    </To>
    <BizMsgIdr>20210301FASTIDJA010HRB12345678</BizMsgIdr>
    <MsgDefIdr>pacs.002.001.10</MsgDefIdr>
    <BizSvc></BizSvc>
    <CreDt>2021-03-01T12:00:00</CreDt>
    <CpyDplct></CpyDplct>
    <PssblDplct></PssblDplct>
    <Sgntr></Sgntr>
</AppHdr>
```

Other than that you can use [JSON Transform Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/json-Transform-Mediator/). Here you can control how the transformation handles Null values by setting different synapse properties. If you want fine control over the transformation. You can use the `Datamapper Mediator`, XSLT transformation or manually construct the Payload using the `PayloadFactory mediator`.